# Datetick not showing enough tick marks in plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a code (below) which plots simple x, y data. My time (x-axis) was originally in numbers from 1-1257 which corresponded to the number of days I was looking at. I converted that to serial dates in order to plot it. However, when it is plotted in MATLAB, there isn't enough labels on the x-axis. When I try to set more tick marks, I either get the labels back in serial format (I want 'mmm yyyy' format), or when I try NumTicks, I get a lot of labels, but they are incorrect since they are just the original labels repeated several times.

```
% Find indexes at which the lat and lon match the conditions
lon_ind = find(X(:,1) == 224); % Longitude closest to  136 03.56W
lat_ind = find(Y(1,:) == -66.75); % Latitude closest to 66 39.67S

% Pull out all the data at the point 2240W and 66.75
data_point = data_All(lon_ind, lat_ind, :); 
t = 1:1257; % Days 1:1257 inclusive. 20100101 to 20130611
y = reshape(data_point,[],1); % Change data_point into a 1 column matrix 

x = datenum(2009, 12, 31) + t; % Convert t into serial numbers

% str = datestr(x, 'mmm yyyy'); % Choose format for x-axis
plot(x, y); % Plot data

datetick('x','mmm yyyy','keeplimits', 'keepticks'); % Set parameters

% NumTicks = 30;
% L = get(gca,'XLim');
% set(gca,'XTick',linspace(L(1),L(2),NumTicks))

set(gca,'XMinorTick','on','YMinorTick','on'); % Add minor ticks (without labels)
```

How can I make it so the x-axis has more labels in the 'mmm yyyy' format?

Comment: This is one of the biggest MATLAB annoyances, happening everytime

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code worked great after only switching some statements around! The trick is to first increase the number of ticks, and *then* call datetick.

With 30 dateticks, the labels are of course way too crowded for any decent plot. As a solution, I downloaded [xticklabelrotate](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabelrotate) from the file-exchange.

Here is the modified code. I used dummy y-data so that others could play with a workable example.

```
t = 1:1257; % Days 1:1257 inclusive. 20100101 to 20130611
y = t.^2;
x = datenum(2009, 12, 31) + t;

str = datestr(x, 'mmm yyyy');
plot(x, y);

NumTicks = 30;
L = get(gca,'XLim');
set(gca,'XTick',linspace(L(1),L(2),NumTicks))

datetick('x','mmm yyyy','keeplimits', 'keepticks')
xticklabel_rotate;
set(gca,'XMinorTick','on','YMinorTick','on')
```

The result looks something like this:

[image]

For any real world application, never forget to label the axes! :-)

**EDIT**

Using the above code to evenly distribute a number of xticks in over a given time-period is a bad idea, especially when combining it with a date-format that only gives the date very "roughly".

Instead, you should place your ticks at the beginning of the months, otherwise the casual viewer will be mislead.

Instead I propose to use this code:

```
t = 1:1257; % Days 1:1257 inclusive. 20100101 to 20130611
y = t.^2;
x = datenum(2009, 12, 31) + t;

str = datestr(x, 'mmm yyyy');
plot(x, y);

tick_locations = datenum(2009,10:1:54,1);
set(gca,'XTick',tick_locations)

datetick('x','mmm yyyy','keeplimits', 'keepticks')
xticklabel_rotate;
```

Here, the labels are spaced in 1-month intervals between Oct 2009 until 54 months later, which works out to June 2013. (Numbers found by trial and error.)

[image]

The ticks are now always at the beginning of a month, which means the space between them is a bit different from month to month, as it should be. (28 days for FEB-MAR, 31 days for MAR-APR)

Comment: Thanks! I went back and added the labels and title.

Comment: Can you explain how you knew to use datenum(2009,10:1:54,1);? What does the 10:1:54,1 part mean?

Comment: `10:1:54` is the vector `[10,11,12,..., 53, 54]`. By using a vector in one of the inputs of `datenum`, the output will also be a vector. The number 10 through 54 stand for the months in the date. Matlab is smart enough to interpret any month between 12 and 24 to be "in the next year", any month between 24 and 36 "two years after", and so on. Sadly, this does not work for negative months.

Comment: Thats great, the only thing is that I cannot make XMinorTick to work with:   set(gca,'XMinorTick','on','YMinorTick','on') . No MinorTicks appear on x. Any clue?thanks

Comment: Strange - it works for me, at least when applying `XMinorTick`s to the example above.

Comment: I am still seeking for some packaged solution for  i.e. 10 or 5 axis labels instead of the MATLAB default choice: 1. Annoying at the best sense.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix that I used for this problem is to increase the width of the plot BEFORE applying datetick.

The plot width can then be reduced back down as needed.

This solution is a bit of a dodgy fix, and is not nearly as capable as Martin's.

```
set(gcf,'Position',[xPos yPos width height]);
datetick
```

Comment: How can I find out what kind of values would work? Can you give an example? Why would the plot width be reduced back down?